# How Nginx is tracking number of connections for least_conn load balancing?

Tags: nginx

How Nginx is tracking number of connections for least_conn load balancing?

How does it actually knows that one server has N connections and another N+k?

Answer (score 3):

Nginx knows because it tracks the number of "peers" that each connection has, and can thus select the backend with the least number of peer connections.

Here's the algorithm used in the [Nginx source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/645697f111983089fdcee0694d17480e0a05a3a5/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_least_conn_module.c#L154).

```
    /*
     * select peer with least number of connections; if there are
     * multiple peers with the same number of connections, select
     * based on round-robin
     */

    if (best == NULL
        || peer->conns * best->weight < best->conns * peer->weight)
    {
        best = peer;
        many = 0;
        p = i;

    } else if (peer->conns * best->weight == best->conns * peer->weight) {
        many = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Is it "in memory" tracking?

Comment: I'm aware of no references to files being used to track this information. Tracking in-memory would be a good fit for Nginx tracking this data because there's a relatively small amount of it and memory-based access would preform faster.